# Checking for multiple adjacent equivalent values in a list

Tags: python, list

I am completing a challenge on codewars and dont understand some very shorthand solutions. You are checking to see if there are three adjacent equivalent values in one list and two adjacent equivalent values of the SAME number in another list. i.e '12777456' (when in list form) would have three 7's in a row. The solution that i dont understand says:

```
def triple_double(num1, num2):
    for x in range(10):
        if str(x) * 3 in str(num1):
            if str(x) * 2 in str(num2):
                return 1
    return 0
```

I dont get the `str(x) * 3 in str(num1)` part. This is shorthand for something and not sure what to google to figure out what it is. Any direction is appreciated thanks! link to codewars:

[Codewars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/triple-trouble-1/python)

Comment: Did you try something like `str(7)*3` in a Python shell to see what it means? Just test it, much quicker than asking on Stack Overflow.

Comment: thanks John this is a good point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes just printing things can help you figure out what's going on. See the modification:

```
num1 = 1233345
num2 = 123345

for x in range(10):
    if str(x) * 3 in str(num1):
        print(str(x) * 3, "in", num1)
        if str(x) * 2 in str(num2):
            print(str(x) * 2, "in", num2)
```

Results in:

```
333 in 1233345
33 in 123345
```

Multiplying strings by ints in Python causes a repeat of the string:

```
>>> "a" * 3
'aaa'
>>> "abc" * 3
'abcabcabc'
```

Comment: this is a great idea, probably should have thought of it, thanks for the nice response much appreciated